# Wordpress dynamic tag to handle feed multivalue data

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have an external feed that is queried for some dynamic data to go onto a page. The data is in an array and each element has a number of attributes. Here is an example of the JSON of the query result:

```
[
   {
      'name': "place1",
      'address': "address1",
      'link': "HTTP://test.com/link1"
   },
   {
      'name': "place2",
      'address': "address2",
      'link': "HTTP://test.com/link2"
   },
...
]
```

I would like to be able to make the attributes available to template sections so I can display the different locations on one page. I think I can do that with custom dynamic tags but I don't know how to do it.